# Regex with Conditional value

Tags: c#

I have the following Regex:

```
String regex = @"^(?<Direction>[+-])(?<Property>[A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]*)$";
```

I am parsing strings like "+name" and "-name" where +/- is the direction:

```
public class Rule
  public Direction Direction { get; }
  public String Property { get; }
}

public enum Direction { Asc, Desc }


public static Rule Parse(String source) {

  Match match = Regex.Match(value, _pattern);

  String property = match.Groups["Property"].Value;
  Direction direction = match.Groups["Direction"].Value == "+" ? Direction.Asc : Direction.Desc;
  Rule rule = new OrderRule(property, direction);
  return true;    
}
```

In this moment it is working as follows:

```
 "+name" => Direction = Asc and Property = Name   
 "-name" => Direction = Desc and Property = Name
```

I need to be able to use it with "name". The omission of +/- makes Direction = Asc.

```
 "name" => Direction = Asc and Property = Name
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make `[+-]` part optional by adding a question mark after it. After that the `"Direction"` group would return an empty string for a missing sign; check for minus instead, and set `Direction.Asc` both for `"+"` and `""`:

```
var regex = @"^(?<Direction>[+-]?)(?<Property>[A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]*)$";
...
var direction = match.Groups["Direction"].Value == "-" ? Direction.Desc: Direction.Asc;
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/rCrkh3)